# remove leading zeros php skip leading string

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP.

I have fields returning from a database that are our stock numbers.

e.g.  `C000001204` and also `GC00001204`

I hope to remove the leading zeros but keep the prefix of `C` and `GC`.  I do not wish to remove the `0` in between the `2` and the `4`.

I had a good search for this however I could only find solutions that ltrim the start.

Thanks in advance!

Andy

Answer (score 2):

Regex ([preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)) would work well here:

```
$str = 'C000000001204';
$str = preg_replace('/^(\D*)0*/', '$1', $str);
```

### Demo

Comment: Really appreciate your quick reply.  If I had different stock codes for example D000001204.  I would like it to bypass any non numeric characters.

Comment: @AndrewJohnson I've updated it. `\D*` will capture non-digits.